# Kendo Scheduler Current Month in Controller (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to get on the ServerSide the current month we are in the Scheduler, but i didn't find anything about it...

How can i send the current month/year to my mvc controller in the Read operation?

I need those informations to fetch new Data from database when we change month in scheduler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution we found!

In the DataSource.Read we added the .Data(javaScriptFunctionName)

```
.DataSource(ds =>
{
    ds.Model(model => model.Id(x => x.Id));
    ds.Read(read => read.Action("Lister", "Calendrier").Data("getAdditionalData"));
})
```

The javascript to get the data we are looking for

```
function getAdditionalData() {
    var scheduler = $("#schedulerCalendrier").data("kendoScheduler");

    var result = {
        start: scheduler.view().startDate().toISOString(),
        end: scheduler.view().endDate().toISOString()
    }

    return result;
}
```

and in the controller we put those properties

```
public ActionResult Lister([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, DateTime start, DateTime end)
```